# Angular2- Passing states of flag between header and sidebar components

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template

I was working on Angular2 project where I have a folder called layout where I split common layouts of certain pages into 3 other components(3 folders-header,sidebar, and footer). I have an anchor tag(...) on my header. Upon hitting on it I need to extend the header upto the left end of screen and at the same time sidebar need to be hidden. On hitting the anchor tag again both should came into actual position(toggling).  I tried like
[ngClass]="{'hide-sidebar' : flags}" class="fix-header"...

where flags is a boolean variable and toggles it's value on hitting anchor tag. I stored the state of this variable in localStorage so that it can be accessed on sidebar, another component.
but this helped me to extend header to left end of screen and sidebar remain unchanged.

I think there can be another logic for achieving both in same hit on anchor tag(button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Communication using @input and @Output**

if the components are in parent-child relationship e.g. navbar-component is in header-component template or header-component is in navbar-component template, then you can use angular `@Input` `@Output` decorators to pass data between components
More on `@Input` and `@Output` and Component interaction in angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction)

**Communication Using Service**

if these components are not directly related then, you can use a `service` to communicate between these components, where one component pushes data to service and the other gets it from the service,
More on communication among components using a service is explained in Angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

**Update: Siblings with Same Parent Communication Using `@Input()` `@Output()`**

If you don't want to use service for communication and keep things less complex, you can use the common parent for sibling components.
Lets suppose the variable which you want to toggle resides in header component,
now you create an `EventEmitter` in your header.component.ts like this

```
@Output() onToggle = new EventEmitter();
```

then in the function where you toggle the variable,
you can write this,

```
toggle() {
    if(this.flags === true) {
       this.flags = false;
    }else {
       this.flags = true;
     }
    this.onToggle.emit(this.flags);
    
}
```

then in your parent template, you'll bind the function to the header which will be executed when the above event is triggered,
so in your parent template you can write this,

```
<app-header (onToggle)="notifySidebar($event)"></app-header>
```

And the `notifySidebar` method in you parent.component.ts will be like this,

```
notifySidebar(flags) {
   console.log(flags);
   this.flags = flags;
}
```

You need to define the above `flags` property (you can choose any name) in parent.component.ts,
Now the final part, you need to tell the sidebar.component.ts that you flag property has changed, so you will define `@Input()` property in your sidebar.component.ts

```
@Input() flags: boolean;
```

and a method `ngOnChanges` (keep in mind to use `ngOnChanges` you need to implement `OnChanges` interface on your sidebar.component.ts more on `OnChanges` [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges) )

```
ngOnChanges() {
  if(this.flags){
    //do whatever you want to do with flags
}
}
```

and the `flags` property will be passed to the sidebar from parent like this

```
<app-sidebar [flags]="flags"></app-sidebar>
```

Comment: Thanks brother. But unfortunately that's not work in my case. My components are not in parent-child relationship but they are siblings(children of same class(say layout))

Comment: Then you can write a service for their communication, as I've outlined it too in my answer and also gave the link to the documentation for better understanding

Comment: True,  Whats your opinion on using input and output since they are having a same parent